# Limit number of files(blocks) in a hadoop data set?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hadoop-streaming, vowpalwabbit

I have [a problem](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/issues/302) with a hadoop data set being split into too many data blocks.

1. Given an already present hadoop data set, is there a way to combine its blocks into fewer but larger blocks?
2. Is there a way to give `pig` or `hadoop-streaming.jar` (cloudera) an upper limit on the number of blocks they split the output into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you want a higher block size, set the desired block size value on the corresponding job only on the pig script

   `set dfs.block.size 134217728;`

Alternatively you can also increase minimum split size, because the split size is calculated based on the formula

```
max(minsplitsize, min(maxsplitsize, blocksize))

set mapred.min.split.size 67108864
```

2. Restricting the number of blocks created is not possible it has to be controlled by `minsplitsize`, `maxsplitsize` and `blocksize` parameters only.

Comment: yes, mappers are directly proportional to the input splits...don't forget to upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another option for reducing the number of output files is to do a random grouping. You can look at the following sample Pig script (replacing *original*, *original_fields* and the arbitrarily chosen number *100* with their actual, sensible replacements):

```
with_rnd = FOREACH original GENERATE *, (int)(RANDOM() * 100) AS rnd;

grouped = GROUP with_rnd BY rnd;

flattened = FOREACH grouped GENERATE FLATTEN(with_rnd);

output = FOREACH flattened GENERATE original_fields;
```

Obviously, this is, technically, unnecessary work, but if your store function doesn't provide another way to do this it will work. Note also that this will not generate 100 files, but a reasonably chosen number for the grouping will reduce the amount considerably, especially if your original data was filtered heavily and had many small files.